# Help With Important Conundrum

Tags: games

I want to know if I can use Ubuntu, while also accessing the gaming prospects of windows 10, and how to do so.

Comment: Nah, for gaming you should stick to windows, because default ubuntu graphics driver isn't capable to reach same performance, unless you will play 2D games and simple 3D games.

Answer (score 2):

- **Native** - Many games support running on Ubuntu natively, without Windows 10.
- **Wine** - Wine is a "compatibility layer" allowing some Windows applications to run. However performance isn't great and many games refuse to start.
- **[Dual Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)** - You can install Ubuntu and Windows 10 alongside eachother. When you start the computer, you will get a prompt asking which operating system you want to boot into.
- **[VGA Passthrough](https://wiki.debian.org/VGAPassthrough)** - A little complex to set up and requires two graphics cards.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the games you want to run and the requirements they have.

I would use playonlinux, It can be easily downloaded here https://www.playonlinux.com/ I run Star Wars the Old Republic on Ubuntu 15.10 with playonlinux without any problem.

You just have to remember that the default graphics driver is nouveau which has no 3d support so you will want to install the specific driver for your graphics card. If you are willing to do some debugging and .dll installs then you can make most games work.